# Widget title showing below widget

Tags: widgets, title

I added a widget area to my sidebar using the following code. The area shows up fine, and I can add widgets which also show up and work fine. The problem I am having is if I add a title to the Widget, it shows up under the widget for some reason. I attached an image to show what is happening.

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'name' => 'Widget Area 2 - Right Sidebar',
        'id' => 'widget_area_2_right_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<aside>',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    )
);
```

[image]

Comment: This is more likely to do with the code of the widget itself. Are you using a Core widget or a custom one?

Comment: It's just a text widget, not a custom one.

Comment: Can you share what you entered in the text widget, and the HTML output that goes with the screenshot? It sounds like it could be a CSS quirk. You might want to try setting `before_widget` and `after_widget` to `''` (empty strings) to see if the extra `<aside>` tags are affecting anything.

Comment: I have a short code for a function I created. It appears that is the issue. I tried just some random text, and it worked fine. I also tried other widgets, and they also worked fine.

Comment: It's probably because you are using PHP's `echo` when you need to `return` instead.